# How can I generate the exe application from python file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, tkcalendar

I'm trying to get the .exe file from this script using pyinstaller

I used this command **pyinstaller -w -F test.py** while I'm in the test directory

the file test.py contains

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

root = Tk()
date = DateEntry(root, year=2001, month=11, day=11, width=17,)
date.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The .exe file that I get is not WORKING?

when I do this **pyinstaller -F test.py** I get the error of no module named babel.numbers on the console

Comment: Have you tried `cx_Freeze`

Comment: No. @RahulAgarwal

Comment: I find it very easy and better than other packages..there are plenty of answers in SO for the same

Comment: I usually use `cx_Freeze`, `py2exe` or `nuitka`; `pyInstaller` most often gives me trouble. Any reason you can't install Python on a client's machine?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal i will try it

Comment: @AgiHammerthief what do you mean with Any reason you can't install Python on a client's machine?

Comment: Remove `-w` flag and run the executable from the command line and give us the error.

Comment: the error i get on cmd is no module named babel.numbers @M.R.

Comment: Can you put the full error trace on the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that PyInstaller can't resolve module `babel.numbers` for `tkcalendar`. One easy way is to use [`hidden-import`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-hidden-import):

```
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import "babel.numbers" test.py
```

Comment: Use a [virtualenv](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) install Pyinstaller and `tkcalendar`. Also, put a `print` statement on the first line and make sure that you see it in console output (remember to **don't use `-w` flag).

Comment: thanx it worked without virtual envirenment