# Making an executable from python does not work

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyinstaller

I have for the past 6 hours been trying to make my code into an executable. I have used pyinstaller and have also tried auto-py-to-exe. However when I proceed to convert the file there is a bunch of missing modules etc. I have a couple import:

```
from calendar import Calendar
from datetime import date
import sys
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning
from tkinter.tix import MAX, CheckList
sys.path.append(r'c:\users\a384663\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages')
from errno import ERANGE
from importlib.metadata import entry_points
from itertools import count
from tkinter import Frame, Spinbox, StringVar, Toplevel, filedialog
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import HORIZONTAL, X
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox, Progressbar
from tkinter import *
from turtle import done
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.path as mplPath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkcalendar import Calendar
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
```

And from my knowledge nothing seems fishy here? However, when I start the procedure I get the following warning file in my dist folder:

(I have cut out some parts in order for it to fit on here)

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional), setuptools.sandbox (conditional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named grp - imported by subprocess (optional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional), gevent.subprocess (optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), subprocess (optional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional), psutil (optional), gevent.subprocess (optional)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named urllib.FancyURLopener - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._sourcemod_builtins (conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib.urlretrieve - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._php_builtins (conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib.urlopen - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._lua_builtins (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._postgres_builtins (conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib.getproxies_environment - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass_environment - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.getproxies - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.urlencode - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.unquote_plus - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.quote_plus - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.unquote - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional), gevent.pywsgi (optional)
missing module named urllib.quote - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.pathname2url - imported by urllib (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional), importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), test.support (delayed, conditional, optional), IPython.utils.timing (optional), psutil._pslinux (optional)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level), PyInstaller.loader.pyimod02_archive (delayed)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), numba.testing.main (optional)
missing module named fcntl - imported by xmlrpc.server (optional), zmq.eventloop.minitornado.platform.posix (top-level), psutil._compat (delayed, optional), gevent.fileobject (optional), gevent.os (optional), gevent.subprocess (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional), IPython.core.page (delayed, optional), prompt_toolkit.input.vt100 (top-level), psutil._compat (delayed, optional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), requests.utils (delayed, conditional, optional), babel.localtime._win32 (optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional), pygments.formatters.img (optional)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.cpu_count - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), gevent.testing.testrunner (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.freeze_support - imported by multiprocessing (conditional), numba.runtests (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.Pool - imported by multiprocessing (delayed, conditional), scipy._lib._util (delayed, conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.Process - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), jupyter_client.ssh.tunnel (top-level), gevent.tests.test__issue600 (top-level)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional), pstats (conditional, optional)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named 'win32com.gen_py' - imported by win32com (conditional, optional), C:\Users\a384663\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py (top-level)
missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by C:\Users\a384663\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py (top-level), C:\Users\a384663\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py (top-level)
missing module named _manylinux - imported by packaging._manylinux (delayed, optional), setuptools._vendor.packaging._manylinux (delayed, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging._manylinux (delayed, optional)
missing module named railroad - imported by pyparsing.diagram (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.more_itertools' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.jaraco.functools (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.importlib_resources' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.jaraco.text (optional)
missing module named 'typing.io' - imported by importlib.resources (top-level)
missing module named 'com.sun' - imported by numba.misc.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by debugpy.common.compat (conditional), gevent._compat (conditional), gevent.monkey (conditional), gevent.testing.six (conditional), gevent.builtins (optional), gevent._ffi.loop (conditional), gevent.libev.corecffi (conditional), gevent.backdoor (delayed, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (conditional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (conditional)
missing module named ordereddict - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (optional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (optional)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.appdirs - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.jaraco' - imported by pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.jaraco.text (top-level)
missing module named Tkinter - imported by tkcalendar.dateentry (optional), tkcalendar.tooltip (optional)
missing module named cdecimal - imported by babel._compat (conditional, optional)
missing module named cPickle - imported by pycparser.ply.yacc (delayed, optional), pickleshare (optional), babel._compat (conditional), gevent._tblib (delayed, optional)
missing module named copy_reg - imported by cPickle (top-level), cStringIO (top-level), gevent._tblib (delayed, optional)
missing module named StringIO - imported by PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph.zipio (conditional), six (conditional), urllib3.packages.six (conditional), requests.compat (conditional), babel._compat (conditional)
missing module named cStringIO - imported by cPickle (top-level), cffi.ffiplatform (optional), xlrd.timemachine (conditional), babel._compat (conditional), gevent.tests.test__pywsgi (optional)
missing module named sets - imported by pytz.tzinfo (optional)
missing module named UserDict - imported by attr._compat (conditional), pytz.lazy (optional)
missing module named tkFont - imported by tkcalendar.calendar_ (optional)
missing module named ttk - imported by tkcalendar.dateentry (optional), tkcalendar.calendar_ (optional), tkcalendar.tooltip (optional)
missing module named 'nose.plugins' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level), numpy.testing._private.nosetester (delayed)
missing module named pickle5 - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (optional), numba.cloudpickle.compat (conditional, optional)
missing module named _dummy_thread - imported by cffi.lock (conditional, optional), numpy.core.arrayprint (optional)
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), scipy.interpolate.interpolate (top-level), scipy.linalg.decomp (top-level), scipy.linalg.decomp_schur (top-level), scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve.utils (top-level), scipy.interpolate._fitpack_impl (top-level), scipy.interpolate.fitpack2 (top-level), scipy.stats.stats (top-level), scipy.optimize.lbfgsb (top-level), scipy.optimize.tnc (top-level), scipy.optimize.slsqp (top-level), scipy.integrate._ode (top-level), scipy.misc.common (top-level), scipy.stats.morestats (top-level)
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), IPython.core.magics.namespace (delayed, conditional, optional), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level), pandas.compat.numpy.function (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level), scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure (top-level), scipy.stats.mstats_basic (top-level), scipy.stats.mstats_extras (top-level)
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level), scipy.optimize.minpack (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), scipy.linalg.decomp (top-level), scipy.linalg._decomp_ldl (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), scipy.stats.morestats (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), scipy.linalg.matfuncs (top-level), scipy.stats.morestats (top-level)
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.lib.twodim_base (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.ufunc - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ones - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.hstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_1d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_3d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.vstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.linspace - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.index_tricks (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.roll - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.take - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.result_type - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.float_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.bool_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.inf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.array2string - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isscalar - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isinf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isnat - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ndarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.array_repr - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.arange - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.transpose - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.function_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.iinfo - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.twodim_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.argsort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sign - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isnan - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)

missing module named _curses - imported by curses (top-level), curses.has_key (top-level)
runtime module named six.moves - imported by cycler (top-level), dateutil.rrule (top-level), dateutil.tz.tz (top-level), dateutil.tz._factories (top-level), dateutil.tz.win (top-level), asttokens.asttokens (top-level)
missing module named six.moves.xrange - imported by six.moves (top-level), asttokens.asttokens (top-level)
missing module named six.moves.range - imported by six.moves (top-level), dateutil.rrule (top-level)
missing module named six.moves.zip - imported by six.moves (top-level), cycler (top-level)
missing module named dateutil.tz.tzfile - imported by dateutil.tz (top-level), dateutil.zoneinfo (top-level)
missing module named olefile - imported by PIL.MicImagePlugin (top-level), PIL.FpxImagePlugin (top-level)
missing module named pygments.formatters.LatexFormatter - imported by pygments.formatters (delayed), IPython.lib.display (delayed)
missing module named numpy.unsignedinteger - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.double - imported by numpy (top-level), scipy.optimize._nnls (top-level)
missing module named numpy.greater - imported by numpy (top-level), scipy.optimize.minpack (top-level)
missing module named numpy.float64 - imported by numpy (top-level), scipy.optimize.lbfgsb (top-level)
missing module named numpy.sign - imported by numpy (top-level), scipy.linalg.matfuncs (top-level)

missing module named numba.typed.List - imported by numba.typed (delayed), numba.core.typing.typeof (delayed), numba.core.codegen (delayed), numba.typed.listobject (delayed), sparse._compressed.convert (top-level)
missing module named graphviz - imported by llvmlite.binding.analysis (delayed), numba.core.ir (delayed, optional), numba.core.controlflow (delayed, optional), numba.misc.inspection (delayed, optional), numba.core.codegen (delayed)
missing module named llvmlite.ir.Value - imported by llvmlite.ir (delayed), llvmlite.ir.types (delayed)
missing module named llvmlite.ir.Constant - imported by llvmlite.ir (delayed), llvmlite.ir.types (delayed), numba.cpython.unicode (top-level)
missing module named llvmlite.ir.GlobalVariable - imported by llvmlite.ir (delayed), llvmlite.ir.types (delayed)
missing module named llvmlite.ir.Module - imported by llvmlite.ir (delayed), llvmlite.ir.types (delayed)
missing module named numba.core.types.WrapperAddressProtocol - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.experimental.function_type (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.FunctionPrototype - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.experimental.function_type (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.UndefinedFunctionType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.experimental.function_type (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.FunctionType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.experimental.function_type (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.Tuple - imported by numba.core.types (delayed), numba.core.types.iterators (delayed), numba.core.types.npytypes (delayed)
missing module named numba.core.types.Array - imported by numba.core.types (delayed), numba.core.types.abstract (delayed)
missing module named numba.np.ufunc.tbbpool - imported by numba.np.ufunc (delayed, conditional, optional), numba.np.ufunc.parallel (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named cuda - imported by numba.core.config (delayed, conditional, optional), numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver (conditional)
missing module named 'elftools.elf' - imported by numba.core.codegen (delayed)
missing module named elftools - imported by numba.core.codegen (delayed)
missing module named r2pipe - imported by numba.misc.inspection (delayed, optional)
missing module named com - imported by numba.misc.appdirs (delayed)
missing module named numba.types.uint64 - imported by numba.types (top-level), numba.cuda.mathimpl (top-level)
missing module named numba.types.int64 - imported by numba.types (top-level), numba.cuda.libdevicefuncs (top-level), numba.cuda.mathimpl (top-level)
missing module named numba.types.float64 - imported by numba.types (top-level), numba.cuda.libdevicefuncs (top-level), numba.cuda.mathimpl (top-level)
missing module named numba.types.float32 - imported by numba.types (top-level), numba.cuda.libdevicefuncs (top-level), numba.cuda.mathimpl (top-level)
missing module named numba.types.Tuple - imported by numba.types (top-level), numba.cuda.libdevicefuncs (top-level)
missing module named numba.types.void - imported by numba.types (top-level), numba.cuda.libdevicefuncs (top-level)
missing module named numba.types.int32 - imported by numba.types (top-level), numba.cuda.libdevicefuncs (top-level)
missing module named numba.types.int16 - imported by numba.types (top-level), numba.cuda.libdevicefuncs (top-level)
missing module named xmlrunner - imported by numba.testing (delayed, conditional)
missing module named git - imported by numba.testing.main (delayed, optional)
missing module named numba.cuda.is_available - imported by numba.cuda (delayed), numba.cuda.testing (delayed)
missing module named numba.core.types.NoneType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.listobject (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.Type - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.listobject (top-level), numba.typed.dictobject (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.ListTypeIteratorType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.listobject (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.ListTypeIterableType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.listobject (top-level)
missing module named yaml - imported by numba.core.config (optional)
missing module named numba.core.types.ListType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.listobject (top-level), numba.typed.typedlist (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.DictIteratorType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.dictobject (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.DictValuesIterableType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.dictobject (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.DictKeysIterableType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.dictobject (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.DictItemsIterableType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.dictobject (top-level)
missing module named numba.core.types.DictType - imported by numba.core.types (top-level), numba.typed.typeddict (top-level), numba.typed.dictobject (top-level)
missing module named numba.typed.Dict - imported by numba.typed (delayed), numba.core.typing.typeof (delayed), numba.typed.dictobject (delayed, conditional), numba.typed.dictimpl (delayed)
missing module named scikits - imported by scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve.linsolve (optional)
missing module named scipy.special.gammaln - imported by scipy.special (top-level), scipy.special.spfun_stats (top-level), scipy.optimize._dual_annealing (top-level), scipy.integrate._quadrature (top-level), scipy.stats._discrete_distns (top-level), scipy.stats._hypotests (top-level), scipy.stats._multivariate (top-level)
missing module named scipy.special.airy - imported by scipy.special (top-level), scipy.special.orthogonal (top-level)
missing module named scipy.special.poch - imported by scipy.special (top-level), scipy.fft._fftlog (top-level)
missing module named scipy.special.loggamma - imported by scipy.special (top-level), scipy.fft._fftlog (top-level)
missing module named scipy.linalg.qr_insert - imported by scipy.linalg (top-level), scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve._gcrotmk (top-level)
missing module named uarray - imported by scipy._lib.uarray (conditional, optional)
missing module named scipy.linalg._flapack_64 - imported by scipy.linalg (optional), scipy.linalg.lapack (optional)
missing module named scipy.linalg._clapack - imported by scipy.linalg (optional), scipy.linalg.lapack (optional)
missing module named scipy.linalg._fblas_64 - imported by scipy.linalg (optional), scipy.linalg.blas (optional)
missing module named scipy.linalg._cblas - imported by scipy.linalg (optional), scipy.linalg.blas (optional)
missing module named botocore - imported by pandas.io.common (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'pyarrow.compute' - imported by pandas.core.arrays.string_arrow (conditional)
missing module named hypothesis - imported by pandas.util._tester (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'lxml.html' - imported by pandas.io.html (delayed)
missing module named iconv_codec - imported by bs4.dammit (optional)
missing module named cchardet - imported by bs4.dammit (optional)
missing module named 'html5lib.treebuilders' - imported by bs4.builder._html5lib (optional)
missing module named 'html5lib.constants' - imported by bs4.builder._html5lib (top-level)
missing module named html5lib - imported by bs4.builder._html5lib (top-level)
missing module named pandas.ExtensionArray - imported by pandas (conditional), pandas.core.construction (conditional)
missing module named toml - imported by pep517.compat (conditional)
missing module named zipp - imported by pep517.meta (optional)
```

My idea was that theres probably an error in pyinstaller or outdated modules? I have tried updating both but it was to no luck.

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: from my experience with pyinstaller/auto-py-to-exe, I always have to create a virtual environment where I install all my dependencies and auto-py-to-exe...if I don't, It will always come up with conflicting issues ...

Comment: @DanielWeigel Alright, so how do you do that? Install every module manually from their git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I made your code work on my side as an executable. I'd say the trick when using auto-py-to-exe for the first 'conversion to exe' time is to select 'Console Based' then once you have the output, launch it from the command line - so in case of errors you can see what is going on and adapt.

Anyways, here's how it worked for me. From the command line:

- cd into your Desktop
- Then 'python -m venv myenv'
- cd into myenv (cd myenv)
- cd into Scripts (cd Scripts)
- type 'activate' then press Enter

Now you are into your virtual environment, install the non built-in packages from your code:

```
pip install pandas
pip install matplotlib
pip install tkcalendar
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

Now your packages are installed, still in the command line( and still with your virtual environment activated ) type :

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

- select your input file ( in my case I took your code + a print() statement so I could have something in my console)
- select the option 'One file'
- select the option 'Console Based'
- then click on 'Convert .py to .exe'

Once your executable is ready , open a new command prompt and navigate (cd) to its folder.
Then type the name of your executable - in my case, it was:

`testfile.exe`

The console prints: 'all good' to me. If it prints something else for you, you will have a more clear indication of the issue you're having from the console.

FYI, the code I used in testfile.py:

```
from calendar import Calendar
from datetime import date
import sys
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning
from tkinter.tix import MAX, CheckList
sys.path.append(r'c:\users\a384663\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages')
from errno import ERANGE
from importlib.metadata import entry_points
from itertools import count
from tkinter import Frame, Spinbox, StringVar, Toplevel, filedialog
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import HORIZONTAL, X
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox, Progressbar
from tkinter import *
from turtle import done
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.path as mplPath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkcalendar import Calendar
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

print('all good')
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I followed your steps but when loading the file in the cmd I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers'` I have tried installing Babel in the virtual environment and its already installed. Im not sure why theres so much trouble, this is my work computer so permission issues perhaps?

Comment: seems like your issue has already been seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902929/how-can-i-generate-the-exe-application-from-python-file

Comment: How about you copy the result command from auto-py-to-exe and you add the flag --hidden-import "babel.numbers"

Comment: I'd recommend just typing `myenv\Scripts\activate` instead of `cd`'ing a couple of times. Way faster. `myenv/bin/activate` on *nix.