# Python EXE file: Why do I get an ImportError when running it?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I converted a python file to exe file, but when I am opening it it's not working. Here is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\python\Python39\site-packages\test\test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
.....
File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
ImportError
[16684] failed to execute script test
```

I don't know what it means. How can I stop this and make my file work?

Comment: There is an "ImportError", looks like you (or the modules you are importing) are trying to import something that the system can't find. Check out this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681770/getting-error-when-using-pynput-with-pyinstaller

Comment: Is there more to that traceback? What did you use to create the .exe? Can you post a [mre] of the code that causes this issue?

Comment: Are you running the exe on the same computer where you ran the original python script?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the import of `pynput` is in bytecode. That makes it impossible for `pyinstaller` to find it: it is a *hidden import*. The documentation has this to say:

> Hidden imports can occur when the code is using `__import__`,
> `imp.find_module()` or perhaps `exec` or `eval`. Hidden imports can also
> occur when an extension module uses the Python/C API to do an import.
> When this occurs, Analysis can detect nothing. There will be no
> warnings, only an ImportError at run-time.
>
> To find these hidden imports, build the app with the --debug=imports
> flag ... and run it.
>
> Once you know what modules are needed, you add the needed modules to
> the bundle using the --hidden-import= command option.