# Python: Failed to execute script

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I wrote a simple script in Python 3.9.5 and converted it to .exe by running

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w myscript.py
```

My script works perfectly fine when I launched it from the python file, but it doesn't work. When I clicked on the .exe file located in the dist folder. It says `Failed to execute script myscript`

I tried creating a much simpler script with only `print("Hello World!")` and converted it to .exe with the exact same steps - It works perfectly fine... I have no idea why my first script did not work.

Here's the code I created:

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import threading

text = pyautogui.prompt('Text: ')
interval = pyautogui.prompt('Interval: ')


def spam():
    while running:
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        pyautogui.write(text)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(float(interval))


running = False


def on_press(key):
    global running
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1:
        running = running ^ True
        if running:
            t = threading.Thread(target=spam)
            t.start()


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

It is basically a simple spam bot (for educational purpose)
[image]

Comment: try adding some logs/print statement and run from cmd. and see logs. of course rebuild the exe before.

Comment: Uhh what do you mean?

Comment: add print statement in between. print something, anything for your reference. try running using python, `python file.py`, you will see console output right.

Comment: I take it you've closely examined the pyinstaller output log to make sure all dependent modules were imported?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Skip step 1 if you don't have 3rd party antivirus. Rest of the steps are still applicable for all cases.

---

**Step 1)** Turn off your 3rd party antivirus

**Step 2)** Turn off windows defender which automatically turns on after 3rd party antivirus deactivation. Type the below code in powershell. Ensure admin powershell and not unprivilleged powershell.

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
```

**Step 3)** Run your exe file

Comment: this doesn't explain why this is required, nor issues with doing this, but it seems logically sound that the process could fail due to OS safety settings

Comment: Nope, doesn't work...Btw, I made another script and it worked fine. The only difference is that 1 has modules and 1 doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
pyinstaller -w --onefile script.py --hidden-import pynput.keyboard._win32 --hidden-import pynput.mouse._win32
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67803996/14278613).

The reason is because `pynput` uses `importlib` to import packages, but PyInstaller could not detect it.

You can also read the [When Things Go Wrong](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports) section about hidden imports.